# Laravel : How to customize title of email when sending email with Mailable?

Tags: laravel-5

I write a `mailable` to send email when user registers,I do it following the document(https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail):

first,generating a mailable:

```
php artisan make:mail UserRegistered
```

Ok,thus there is a `UserRegistered.php` file in the `app/Mail` directory,and I write the `build()` method like this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.activate-user')
                ->with([
                    'name' => $this->user->name,
                    'url' => route('activateUser',['token'=>$this->user->confirmation_token])
                ]);
}
```

The email can be sent successfully,the title of the email is `User Registered`,I want to customize the title ,how to do it?

Answer (score 36):

You have to use `subject` method

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.activate-user')
                ->subject("My mail title")
                ->with([
                    'name' => $this->user->name,
                    'url' => route('activateUser',['token'=>$this->user->confirmation_token])
                ]);
}
```

Or update your mails class's constructor

```
public function __construct()
    {

        $this->subject('Sample title');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change mail title you need to change it in `.env` file. Same Like as given below:

[image]

You need to change it here for mail title.

And if you just want to change only subject then you can you use `subject()` function while sending mail to add you subject.

**For Example:**

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Reset Password')
        ->view('emails.forgotpass');
}
```

and the final result will be like this where my APP_NAME is Laravel.

> **Result 1:**

[image]

> **Result 2:**

[image]